# CrudRepository findAll() By List Contains Sub-list

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

## Preface

I am using Spring Data/JPA/Hibernate etc. and entities (annotated with `javax.persistence.Entity`) that are retrieved via repositories that extend `org.springframework.stereotype.CrudRepository`.

I have an entity, we'll call it `Bob`, and it contains a list of another type of Entity, `Tom`. This list is called `List<Tom> toms;`. This is a many-to-many relationship in my database.

```
@Repository
public interface BobRepository extends CrudRepository<Bob, String> {
    public Iterable<Bob> findAllByTomsContains(List<Tom> toms);
}
```

This is one of the automatically-implemented methods that Spring takes care of for me as long as I name it correctly.

## My question

I need to fetch all Bobs where the provided list of Toms is a sub-set of the toms stored in each Bob. That is, the list I provide to the method is a sub-set of the list stored in the Bob entity.

Right now, with the above code, I am getting a Bob result for each item in the Toms list. So if one of my Bobs has these Toms {"tom-one", "tom-two", "tom-blue"} and I query for {"tom-one", "tom_two"} I am getting two matches to the same tom. Similarly, if I add an additional Tom that doesn't match bob's list, the first matching Tom still does, and is returned. A query like this should match Bobs with all of the listed Toms or more.

What is the appropriate naming convention for my method (currently `findAllByTomsContains`), if this is even possible? My current workaround is many queries by each Tom in the list, merging an intersection of results (slow, painful).

Comment: A very confusing description of the condition )) Could you simplify it, pls? Or provide an illustrative example?..

Comment: @Cepr0 I don't know how to simplify it further... An Entity contains a list of another Entity type. I need to get all of the first entity type from my database, only if the list I provide is a sub-set/list of the list stored in the entity. You'll probably need to be familiar with Spring to answer this question, as the way you name the function changes what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Query("select b from Bob b join b.toms t where t in (?1) group by b having count(t) >= (select count(t2) from Tom t2 where t2 in (?1))")
Iterable<Bob> findIfSubsetOfTomsExists(List<Tom> toms);
```

Or:

```
@Query("select b from Bob b join b.toms t where t in (?1) group by b having count(t) >= ?2")
Iterable<Bob> findIfSubsetOfTomsExists(List<Tom> toms, int tomsCount);

default Iterable<Bob> getIfSubsetOfTomsExists(List<Tom> toms) {
    return findIfSubsetOfTomsExists(toms, toms.size());
}
```

Comment: This sounds right, but it isn't working. It only works if the list toms contains only one item. As soon as I add a second, I get 0 entities returned, whether they should match or not.

Comment: The result of the non-unique version of this is anything matching any combination of tags in the list. So if my query has 4 items in it, any 1, 2, 3 or 4 of those items that match will generate a response of the matching entity. The `distinct`  avoids the duplicates, but does not fix the problem where a match is made for any fewer than all of the items in the query. The returned entities must match all of the items in the query, but may have additional items. If I query {"hi","cat", "moose"} against a Bob with {"hi","cat"} it should fail. The other way around would succeed.

Comment: @BitFracture If the method parameter is [1, 2, 3], then the result must consist only those `Bob`'s, which `toms` have [1, 2, 3] or more? If `Bob`'s `toms` has [1, 2] - it doesn't get to the result; if `Bob`'s `toms` has [1, 2, 3, 4] - it get to the result. Right?

Comment: Right..... that'll do it. Unfortunately, for my purpose, I must avoid dialect-specific queries. This is a valid answer though. I'll mark it, as my multi-query transaction approach works with the addition of an intersect merge method.

Comment: @BitFracture  it's JPQL - dialect independent language

Comment: It looked like SQL at a glance. The more you know! Thanks for the help.